# How do I get the X coordinate for my turtle graphics turtle

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I can create a turtle that will be in a window with the following code:

```
Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w,100,100);
```

If I want to know its coordinates, I can write:

```
int getX(w);
```

But when I have 2 turtles, t1 and t2, I don't know what to do if I want to know turtle1's X coordinates.

```
Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w,100,100);
Turtle t2 = new Turtle(w,200,100);
```

If I were to write `int getX(w)`, which turtles X coordinate would I get? How do I write so I get `t1`s cordinate?

Comment: Someone, not the OP, mistagged this as [python] which is why some of the answers make no sense.  I rolled it back and tagged it as [java] which is my best guess.  Since there are many different turtle packages for Java, it's difficult to answer this question.

Answer (score 6):

Use `turtle.xcor()`
it returns the x position.
Use `turtle.ycor()`
it returns the y position.

Answer (score 0):

**For python turtle module, get the x and y coordinates of the turtle use the getPosition method like this:**

```
import turtle
import time
alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex_text = turtle.Turtle()
alex_text.goto(alex.position()[0], alex.position()[1])
alex_text.write("hello")
time.sleep(1)
```

turtle.position() - Return the turtle’s current location (x,y) (as a Vec2D vector).

Read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html#turtle.write

Answer (score -2):

I have no idea what Turtle class you are using, but I'd imagine you'd do something like this:

```
int x1 = t1.getX(w);
int x2 = t2.getX(w);
```