# Remove column titles when appending dataframe content

Tags: python, dataframe, format, append

I successfully appended DataFrame content via iteration through a loop but i'm also appending the column headers each time.  Is there a parameter i'm missing that will take care of the repeated column headers?  The data i'm seeing is good for analysis but want to clean up the output.

```
results_array=[]
for x in range(1,4):
   scores = my_func(my_model,X,Y,cv = (x+1))
   results = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': col1,'Col2': col2,'Score': scores.mean()},index=[0])
   results_array.append(results)
print((results_array))
```

```
  [   Col1  Col2 Score
  0  John     2  0.08,    Col1  Col2  Score
  0  Suzy     3  0.02,    Col1  Col2  Score
  0  Gary     4  0.01]
```

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155992/how-do-i-get-the-x-coordinate-for-my-turtle-graphics-turtle

Comment: What is the end output you would like? A list or a dataframe?

Comment: Only want to see a column labels one time, not each time I'm appending a new row to the DataFrame