# How do I find the x and y coordinates of the turtle in the turtle graphics module?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want a more efficient way of finding the x and y coordinates of the turtle instead of just counting.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! Have you tried anything? Do you have any code you could share and what you expect? Showing effort means you are asking for help rather than asking for someone to do something for you. Hope that makes sense, if you want to ask good questions I suggest you look at: [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155992/how-do-i-get-the-x-coordinate-for-my-turtle-graphics-turtle

Comment: [turtle.position()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html#turtle.position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in turtle function to find current position.

```
>>>turtle.pos()
(440.00,-0.00)
```

It will return the current location (x,y) as a Vec2D Vector.